# How to use mlogit in r to estimate a binary Probit model

Tags: r, binary-data, mlogit

For binary choice, I know I can use `glm` to estimate a binary Probit model. However, for teaching purpose, since I am going to move on to multinomial choice at a later stage (with more than two alternatives), I try to use `mlogit` package all the way through. The odd thing is that `mlogit` package seems to be unable to deal with a binary Probit problem.

Suppose the data set I imported is called "data.set". The CSV file can be downloaded from [this link](http://goo.gl/8mTEfe).

Here is my program

Given the CSV data has been imported as data.set. I run the following lines.

```
library(mlogit)

data.set2<-mlogit.data(data.set,choice='GRADE',shape='wide')

mlogit(GRADE~ 0 | GPA+TUCE+PSI ,data=data.set2,probit=TRUE)
```

Then I get the error message:

> Error in M[, ((i - 1):(J - 2))] : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In rbind(0, diag(J - 2)) :
>     number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

My "data.set2" is a `mlogit` data frame, which looks like:

```
     GPA TUCE PSI GRADE chid alt
1.0 2.66   20   0  TRUE    1   0
1.1 2.66   20   0 FALSE    1   1
2.0 2.89   22   0  TRUE    2   0
2.1 2.89   22   0 FALSE    2   1
3.0 3.28   24   0  TRUE    3   0
3.1 3.28   24   0 FALSE    3   1
```

Comment: OP needs `binary probit`. Although, it works when `probit` is set to `FALSE`, the answer doesn't match with `glm`.

Comment: And why should there be a "match" for some unspecified bit of code, anyway? There's no "probit" link in `glm`'s list of "families".

Comment: For a probit model with `glm` the link is `binomial` and the family is `probit`.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? See http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/probit.htm or http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html